# Most efficient way to populate a calendar?

Tags: php, mysql

I have built a simple PHP calendar which displays a 12 month period. I have a MySQL database which holds calendar events. I would like to populate my calendar with my events. I could of course run a MySQL query for each day but 365 queries seems very inefficient, as does running a single MySQL query and looping through the results 365 times. What, if any, are the alternatives? Is there a simple, and efficient, way of doing this?

Comment: All depends on the output/UI you want for your calendar.

Comment: Create an array with the days as keys, then use it inside the 1..365 loop.

Comment: What are your table structures?

Comment: Output is via a simple php generated web page (echoed text).

Comment: Table structure is again pretty simple.....5 columns; calendarId (AI, primary kay), calendarDate, eventName, startTime, endTime. I might add more columns on at some point, but can't see that making much difference.

Comment: Why not something like `SELECT * FROM Events WHERE EventDate BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-12-31 23:59:59' ORDER BY EventDate`? If that doesn't do it, perhaps you need to further explain the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT idEvent, day, hour , event from calendar where year = 2014 order by day, hour ";

$calendarEvents = array();

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

   /* fetch associative array */
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

       $calendarEvents[  $row["day"]  ][ $row["idEvent"] ]  = $row;

  }

   /* free result set */
   $result->free();
}
```

Then you have the data from 2014 with 1 query and access them with array $calendarEvents.
For each day you have all events by id, so with foreach loop you get all events for that day with an order same as query order

```
  for($i = 1; $i < 365 ; $i++){

 $date = date("Y-m-d" , strtotime( "2013-12-31 + $i day"));

     foreach( $calendarEvents[ $date ] as $idEvent => $c){

        echo $idEvent . " -- ".$date." - ". $c["hour"]." - ".$c["event"];

     }

 }
```

Comment: I think this is exactly what I am looking for, thanks. If there were more than one event on a particular date, how would I call them all?

Comment: Look for the edit, For each day add elements by id, then with the foreach loop you access all elements for that day.

Answer (score 0):

To give you a result set with one row per day of the year, and all the events (if any) for that day concatenated into another column you could do something like this:-

```
SELECT DateSub.aDay, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(':', SomeCalendarTable.eventName, SomeCalendarTable.startTime, SomeCalendarTable.endTime)) AS DaysEvents
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE_ADD('2014/01/01', INTERVAL (Units.DayNo + Tens.DayNo * 10 + Hundreds.DayNo * 100) DAY) AS aDay
    FROM
    (SELECT 1 AS DayNo UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) Units,
    (SELECT 1 AS DayNo UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) Tens,
    (SELECT 1 AS DayNo UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 0) Hundreds
    HAVING YEAR(aDay) = '2014' 
) DateSub
LEFT OUTER JOIN SomeCalendarTable
ON DateSub.aDay = SomeCalendarTable.calendarDate
GROUP BY DateSub.aDay
```